# Docker jetty container JVM memory allocation

Tags: java, docker, jvm, jetty, docker-compose

I am new to using Docker and have written a compose file for my application. It utilizes jetty and MySQL DB. I configured JVM memory for Jetty via **JAVA_OPTS** in the environment parameter.  I thought the maximum memory setting for jetty JVM was 1GB. However, When I run the commands below, it shows that jetty has consumed 2 GB. Please help on how to configure the JVM memory for jetty and ensure the same.

***docker-compose.yml***

```
my-app:
  image: jetty
 environment:
     JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx1024m -Xms128m"
```

***Status CMD***

```
docker stats $(docker ps|grep -v "NAMES"|awk '{ print $NF }'|tr "\n" " ")

CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O               BLOCK I/O
my-app           0.05%               2.188 GB / 10.56 GB   6.39%               12.66 kB / 1.584 kB   57 MB / 45.06 kB
```

Comment: please verify the setting is set correctly in the  config file, `service.cfg` inside the container.

Comment: could you please give more details about service.cfg and what confiuration do I need to verify ? I am new to docker

Comment: its not about docker, its jetty config file, http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYQQ2_5.3.1/com.ibm.rational.change.install.doc/topics/ch_t_ig_change_java_max_heap_jty.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your environment variable's name:

```
my-app:
  image: jetty
 environment:
   JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Xmx1024m -Xms128m"
```

Regards

Comment: Yes, after using JAVA_OPTIONS. it is working good. one more correction in my understanding is status cmd gives memory of container not Jetty. I logged in container by ( docker exec -it container-id /bin/bash) and executed ps -efww command. it shows JAVA OPTIONS. java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/jetty -Xmx1024m -Xms128m -jar /usr/local/jetty/start.jar

Answer (score 0):

When you run java inside container, its not only java, there are other things too, May be my answer is inappropriate to this context but I feel it might help someone in future. Please go through this link [JVM memory optimization in Docker](https://medium.com/@larry.l.fang/jvm-memory-optimisation-in-docker-46cda197295a)